# how do I get dhclient to start when I login and start as root?

Tags: networking, login, network-manager, sudo, dhclient

I've messed up my ubuntu. I uninstalled something that network-manager depended on and now I have to start the dhclient manually every time I log in. I've got a script that does the sudo dhclient eth0 but I have to punch in my password twice to log in: Once for the actual login and twice to get my dhcp running. How can I get dhclient just running automagically at every login?

Comment: Just to make sure: what do you want to tell us with "start as root"? Are you logging in as root?

Answer (score 1):

add this line to the end of `/etc/profile`

`dhclient eth0`

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try; Rebooting

Comment: Why not just sudo apt-get install network-manager ?

Comment: Well when you say it like that the solution seems obvious. Honestly I thought I did that already. Well, make that an "answer" so I can give you credit.

Comment: did you solve the problem?